Retreive original Index from sklearn.neighbors
I am attempting to match 2 datasets using sklearn.neighbors but I cannot figure out how to retain the original index in the output. What I want as final output is the index of row from the dataset dfA and its matched index from the datset dfB.When I print(indicies) the values do not correspond.
   knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors = 1).fit(dfA) distances, indicies = knn.kneighbors(dfB) print(indicies)
